# How do you find the row count for all your tables in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, count, database-table

I'm looking for a way to find the row count for all my tables in Postgres.  I know I can do this one table at a time with:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table_name;
```

but I'd like to see the row count for all the tables and then order by that to get an idea of how big all my tables are.

Answer (score 894, accepted):

There's three ways to get this sort of count, each with their own tradeoffs.

If you want a true count, you have to execute the SELECT statement like the one you used against each table.  This is because PostgreSQL keeps row visibility information in the row itself, not anywhere else, so any accurate count can only be relative to some transaction.  You're getting a count of what that transaction sees at the point in time when it executes.  You could automate this to run against every table in the database, but you probably don't need that level of accuracy or want to wait that long.

```
WITH tbl AS
  (SELECT table_schema,
          TABLE_NAME
   FROM information_schema.tables
   WHERE TABLE_NAME not like 'pg_%'
     AND table_schema in ('public'))
SELECT table_schema,
       TABLE_NAME,
       (xpath('/row/c/text()', query_to_xml(format('select count(*) as c from %I.%I', table_schema, TABLE_NAME), FALSE, TRUE, '')))[1]::text::int AS rows_n
FROM tbl
ORDER BY rows_n DESC;
```

The second approach notes that the statistics collector tracks roughly how many rows are "live" (not deleted or obsoleted by later updates) at any time.  This value can be off by a bit under heavy activity, but is generally a good estimate:

```
SELECT schemaname,relname,n_live_tup 
  FROM pg_stat_user_tables 
ORDER BY n_live_tup DESC;
```

That can also show you how many rows are dead, which is itself an interesting number to monitor.

The third way is to note that the system ANALYZE command, which is executed by the autovacuum process regularly as of PostgreSQL 8.3 to update table statistics, also computes a row estimate.  You can grab that one like this:

```
SELECT 
  nspname AS schemaname,relname,reltuples
FROM pg_class C
LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
WHERE 
  nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') AND
  relkind='r' 
ORDER BY reltuples DESC;
```

Which of these queries is better to use is hard to say.  Normally I make that decision based on whether there's more useful information I also want to use inside of pg_class or inside of pg_stat_user_tables.  For basic counting purposes just to see how big things are in general, either should be accurate enough.

Comment: For completions sake, please add this for the first option (thanks goes to @a_horse_with_no_name): `with tbl as (SELECT table_schema,table_name FROM information_schema.tables
  where table_name not like 'pg_%' and table_schema in ('public'))
  select table_schema, table_name, (xpath('/row/c/text()', query_to_xml(format('select count(*) as c from %I.%I', table_schema, table_name), false, true, '')))[1]::text::int as rows_n from tbl ORDER BY 3 DESC;`

Comment: @Greg Smith Which version introduced `n_live_tup`? My Redshift database lacks that column. It's a derivative of Postgres 8.0.2.

Comment: The 'second approach' query (using `pg_stat_user_tables`) returned mostly zeros in `n_live_tup` for me because `ANALYZE` had never been run. Rather than run `ANALYZE` on every schema/table and wait forever for an answer, I first checked the results using 'third approach' and that one (using `pg_class`) returned very accurate counts.

Comment: @BrianD, it is possible to execute the analyze at database level using analyzedb utility as "analyzedb -d dbname"

Comment: @estani, thanks! Your sql is the only one from this answer where i haven't discovered obvious errors. For example Gregs second approach showed zeros for all tables, and third approach was accurate only in new DB where i restored the dump (compared to the proposed query output actual counts in original DB tables were different)

Comment: @atsu85 I'm marveled you could read that... as it never got added to the post, I've added a [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67356879/1182464), so it's more clear what's happening in it.

Comment: from where i will get a definition for function query_to_xml(Im using Greenplum 4.3.33.3 version)

Comment: FYI, in the query that uses pg_class, reltuples is output in scientific notation. To see it formatted with thousands separators, select the field back as `to_char(reltuples, 'fm999G999G999G999')`.

Comment: Excellent answers. Note that n_live_tup can be very dodgy. I just got 28 for a table with nearly 2000 rows. SELECT COUNT(*) query seems the only way to reliably get an accurate count. I'm surprised Postgres isn't just caching this metadata

Answer (score 161):

Here is a solution that does not require functions to get an accurate count for each table:

```
select table_schema, 
       table_name, 
       (xpath('/row/cnt/text()', xml_count))[1]::text::int as row_count
from (
  select table_name, table_schema, 
         query_to_xml(format('select count(*) as cnt from %I.%I', table_schema, table_name), false, true, '') as xml_count
  from information_schema.tables
  where table_schema = 'public' --<< change here for the schema you want
) t
```

`query_to_xml` will run the passed SQL query and return an XML with the result (the row count for that table). The outer `xpath()` will then extract the count information from that xml and convert it to a number

The derived table is not really necessary, but makes the `xpath()` a bit easier to understand - otherwise the whole `query_to_xml()` would need to be passed to the `xpath()` function.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, will it give any performance issue on busy and huge tables while executing?

Comment: @Spike: performance issues compared to what? The major performance bottleneck is running a `select count(*)` on every table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, by executing x_path function against a 100 million records.

Comment: @Spike: the `xpath()` function is only applied to a **single** row - the result of the `count(*)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I have tried this with some third party databases (Liferay), the tables under the the schema didn't show up. Am I missing anything?

Comment: The application that created the database is irrelevant. The way to "debug" this is to look at the raw XML output, maybe you missed something when copying the xpath expression. Or your Postgres version returns a slightly different XML result.

Comment: This gives a TRUE count and the accepted answer doesn't which is expected. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a similar function for Postgres 8.4? the format function is not available in that version. Thanks!

Comment: @Matias You will need to concatenate (`||`) the schema and table name. If you expect identifiers that need quoting, you will have to use `quote_ident()` together with that. But more importantly: you should plan an upgrade to a supported and maintained version of Postgres **now**.

Comment: I believe the query_to_xml function is not available in postgres 8.4 though. Thanks anyway!

Comment: `query_to_xml` **is** available even in that ancient version: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-xml.html

Comment: order by row_count desc

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, excellent solution. A bit shorter version: ```select schemaname,
       tablename,
       (xpath('/row/cnt/text()', xml_count))[1]::text::int as row_count
from (
       select tablename, schemaname,
              query_to_xml(format('select count(*) as cnt from %I.%I', schemaname, tablename), false, true, '') as xml_count
       FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = current_schema()
     ) t;```

Comment: This is fantastic. Is there a way to filter out db views?

Answer (score 39):

To get estimates, see [Greg Smith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2611745/238814).

To get exact counts, the other answers so far are plagued with some issues, some of them serious (see below). Here's a version that's hopefully better:

```
CREATE FUNCTION rowcount_all(schema_name text default 'public')
  RETURNS table(table_name text, cnt bigint) as
$$
declare
 table_name text;
begin
  for table_name in SELECT c.relname FROM pg_class c
    JOIN pg_namespace s ON (c.relnamespace=s.oid)
    WHERE c.relkind = 'r' AND s.nspname=schema_name
  LOOP
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('select cast(%L as text),count(*) from %I.%I',
       table_name, schema_name, table_name);
  END LOOP;
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

It takes a schema name as parameter, or `public` if no parameter is given.

To work with a specific list of schemas or a list coming from a query without modifying the function, it can be called from within a query like this:

```
WITH rc(schema_name,tbl) AS (
  select s.n,rowcount_all(s.n) from (values ('schema1'),('schema2')) as s(n)
)
SELECT schema_name,(tbl).* FROM rc;
```

This produces a 3-columns output with the schema, the table and the rows count.

Now here are some issues in the other answers that this function avoids:

- Table and schema names shouldn't be injected into executable SQL without being quoted, either with `quote_ident` or with the more modern `format()` function with its `%I` format string. Otherwise some malicious person may name their table `tablename;DROP TABLE other_table` which is perfectly valid as a table name.
- Even without the SQL injection and funny characters problems, table name may exist in variants differing by case. If a table is named `ABCD` and another one `abcd`, the `SELECT count(*) FROM...` must use a quoted name otherwise it will skip `ABCD` and count `abcd` twice. The `%I` of format does this automatically.
- With older versions of Postgres, `information_schema.tables` lists custom composite types in addition to tables, even when table_type is `'BASE TABLE'`. As a consequence, we can't iterate on `information_schema.tables`, otherwise we risk having `select count(*) from name_of_composite_type` and that would fail. OTOH `pg_class where relkind='r'` should always work fine.
- The type of COUNT() is `bigint`, not `int`. Tables with more than 2.15 billion rows may exist (running a count(*) on them is a bad idea, though).
- A permanent type need not to be created for a function to return a resultset with several columns. `RETURNS TABLE(definition...)` is a better alternative.

Answer (score 34):

The hacky, practical answer for people trying to evaluate which Heroku plan they need and can't wait for heroku's slow row counter to refresh:

Basically you want to run `\dt` in `psql`, copy the results to your favorite text editor (it will look like this:

```
 public | auth_group                     | table | axrsosvelhutvw
 public | auth_group_permissions         | table | axrsosvelhutvw
 public | auth_permission                | table | axrsosvelhutvw
 public | auth_user                      | table | axrsosvelhutvw
 public | auth_user_groups               | table | axrsosvelhutvw
 public | auth_user_user_permissions     | table | axrsosvelhutvw
 public | background_task                | table | axrsosvelhutvw
 public | django_admin_log               | table | axrsosvelhutvw
 public | django_content_type            | table | axrsosvelhutvw
 public | django_migrations              | table | axrsosvelhutvw
 public | django_session                 | table | axrsosvelhutvw
 public | exercises_assignment           | table | axrsosvelhutvw
```

), then run a regex search and replace like this:

```
^[^|]*\|\s+([^|]*?)\s+\| table \|.*$
```

to:

```
select '\1', count(*) from \1 union/g
```

which will yield you something very similar to this:

```
select 'auth_group', count(*) from auth_group union
select 'auth_group_permissions', count(*) from auth_group_permissions union
select 'auth_permission', count(*) from auth_permission union
select 'auth_user', count(*) from auth_user union
select 'auth_user_groups', count(*) from auth_user_groups union
select 'auth_user_user_permissions', count(*) from auth_user_user_permissions union
select 'background_task', count(*) from background_task union
select 'django_admin_log', count(*) from django_admin_log union
select 'django_content_type', count(*) from django_content_type union
select 'django_migrations', count(*) from django_migrations union
select 'django_session', count(*) from django_session
;
```

(You'll need to remove the last `union` and add the semicolon at the end manually)

Run it in `psql` and you're done.

```
            ?column?            | count
--------------------------------+-------
 auth_group_permissions         |     0
 auth_user_user_permissions     |     0
 django_session                 |  1306
 django_content_type            |    17
 auth_user_groups               |   162
 django_admin_log               |  9106
 django_migrations              |    19
[..]
```

Comment: In Atom, I had to regex search and replace like this:


`select '$1', count(*) from $1 union/g`

Comment: Also, the post says: "You'll need to remove the union and add the semicolon at the end."

This is a typo. You need to remove `/g` (keep `union`) and add one semicolon (`;`) at the very end. Don't forget to remove the last `union` before the semicolon.

Comment: "Don't forget to remove the last `union` before the semicolon" is what I meant :) Added the word "last" to clarify

Comment: For VSCode what worked for me was `select '$1', count(*) from $1 union`

Answer (score 30):

If you don't mind potentially stale data, you can [access the same statistics used by the query optimizer](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-VIEWS).

Something like:

```
SELECT relname, n_tup_ins - n_tup_del as rowcount FROM pg_stat_all_tables;
```

Comment: @mlissner: If your autovacuum interval is too long or you haven't run a manual `ANALYZE` on the table, the statistics can get way off. Its a question of database load and how the database is configured (if the statistics are updated more frequently, the stats will be more accurate, but it could reduce runtime performance). Ultimately, the only way to get accurate data is to run `select count(*) from table` for all tables.

Answer (score 18):

Simple Two Steps: 
 (Note : No need to change anything - just copy paste) 
**1. create function**

```
create function 
cnt_rows(schema text, tablename text) returns integer
as
$body$
declare
  result integer;
  query varchar;
begin
  query := 'SELECT count(1) FROM ' || schema || '.' || tablename;
  execute query into result;
  return result;
end;
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

**2. Run this query to get rows count for all the tables**

```
select sum(cnt_rows) as total_no_of_rows from (select 
  cnt_rows(table_schema, table_name)
from information_schema.tables
where 
  table_schema not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') 
  and table_type='BASE TABLE') as subq;
```

**or** 
**To get rows counts tablewise**

```
select
  table_schema,
  table_name, 
  cnt_rows(table_schema, table_name)
from information_schema.tables
where 
  table_schema not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') 
  and table_type='BASE TABLE'
order by 3 desc;
```

Answer (score 12):

Not sure if an answer ***in bash*** is acceptable to you, but FWIW...

```
PGCOMMAND=" psql -h localhost -U fred -d mydb -At -c \"
            SELECT   table_name
            FROM     information_schema.tables
            WHERE    table_type='BASE TABLE'
            AND      table_schema='public'
            \""
TABLENAMES=$(export PGPASSWORD=test; eval "$PGCOMMAND")

for TABLENAME in $TABLENAMES; do
    PGCOMMAND=" psql -h localhost -U fred -d mydb -At -c \"
                SELECT   '$TABLENAME',
                         count(*) 
                FROM     $TABLENAME
                \""
    eval "$PGCOMMAND"
done
```

Comment: At its essence, this just boils down to the same `select count(*) from table_name;` in the OP!

Comment: @NoachMagedman - it's an alternative approach - why knock it - basically the OP wants `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM all_tables;`!

Answer (score 12):

Extracted from my Comment in the answer from GregSmith to make it more readable:

```sql
with tbl as (
  SELECT table_schema,table_name 
  FROM information_schema.tables
  WHERE table_name not like 'pg_%' AND table_schema IN ('public')
)
SELECT 
  table_schema, 
  table_name, 
  (xpath('/row/c/text()', 
    query_to_xml(format('select count(*) AS c from %I.%I', table_schema, table_name), 
    false, 
    true, 
    '')))[1]::text::int AS rows_n 
FROM tbl ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```

Thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 10):

I usually don't rely on statistics, especially in PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT table_name, dsql2('select count(*) from '||table_name) as rownum
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type='BASE TABLE'
    AND table_schema='livescreen'
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dsql2(i_text text)
  RETURNS int AS
$BODY$
Declare
  v_val int;
BEGIN
  execute i_text into v_val;
  return v_val;
END; 
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Comment: This is nice but first query should also include the schema for the rownum value. If there are conflicting names in different schemas this will not work as expected. So this part of the query should look more like `dsql2('select count(*) from livescreen.'||table_name)` or better it could be turned into a function of its own.

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me

> SELECT schemaname,relname,n_live_tup FROM pg_stat_user_tables ORDER BY
>   n_live_tup DESC;

Comment: This gives some interesting numbers, but it's not (always?) the row count. OK, the docs say it's estimated: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ALL-TABLES-VIEW (how to update these stats?)

Answer (score 8):

You Can use this query to generate all tablenames with their counts

```
select ' select  '''|| tablename  ||''', count(*) from ' || tablename ||' 
union' from pg_tables where schemaname='public';
```

the result from the above query will be

```
select  'dim_date', count(*) from dim_date union 
select  'dim_store', count(*) from dim_store union
select  'dim_product', count(*) from dim_product union
select  'dim_employee', count(*) from dim_employee union
```

You'll need to remove the last union and add the semicolon at the end !!

```
select  'dim_date', count(*) from dim_date union 
select  'dim_store', count(*) from dim_store union
select  'dim_product', count(*) from dim_product union
select  'dim_employee', count(*) from dim_employee  **;**
```

RUN !!!

Answer (score 6):

I don't remember the URL from where I collected this.  But hope this should help you:

```
CREATE TYPE table_count AS (table_name TEXT, num_rows INTEGER); 

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_em_all () RETURNS SETOF table_count  AS '
DECLARE 
    the_count RECORD; 
    t_name RECORD; 
    r table_count%ROWTYPE; 

BEGIN
    FOR t_name IN 
        SELECT 
            c.relname
        FROM
            pg_catalog.pg_class c LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
        WHERE 
            c.relkind = ''r''
            AND n.nspname = ''public'' 
        ORDER BY 1 
        LOOP
            FOR the_count IN EXECUTE ''SELECT COUNT(*) AS "count" FROM '' || t_name.relname 
            LOOP 
            END LOOP; 

            r.table_name := t_name.relname; 
            r.num_rows := the_count.count; 
            RETURN NEXT r; 
        END LOOP; 
        RETURN; 
END;
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Executing `select count_em_all();` should get you row count of all your tables.

Comment: It's good idea to quote column names (like `quote_ident(t_name.relname)`) to ensure proper support for unusual names ("column-name", for example).

Comment: To drop it afterwards: DROP FUNCTION count_em_all();

Comment: Got an error: select count_em_all(); ERROR: syntax error at or near "group" LINE 1: SELECT COUNT() AS "count" FROM group ^ QUERY: SELECT COUNT() AS "count" FROM group CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function count_em_all() line 18 at FOR over EXECUTE statement

Comment: Great! To select and sort -  `SELECT * FROM count_em_all() as r ORDER BY r.num_rows DESC;`

Answer (score 5):

I made a small variation to include all tables, also for non-public tables.

```
CREATE TYPE table_count AS (table_schema TEXT,table_name TEXT, num_rows INTEGER); 

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_em_all () RETURNS SETOF table_count  AS '
DECLARE 
    the_count RECORD; 
    t_name RECORD; 
    r table_count%ROWTYPE; 

BEGIN
    FOR t_name IN 
        SELECT table_schema,table_name
        FROM information_schema.tables
        where table_schema !=''pg_catalog''
          and table_schema !=''information_schema''
        ORDER BY 1,2
        LOOP
            FOR the_count IN EXECUTE ''SELECT COUNT(*) AS "count" FROM '' || t_name.table_schema||''.''||t_name.table_name
            LOOP 
            END LOOP; 

            r.table_schema := t_name.table_schema;
            r.table_name := t_name.table_name; 
            r.num_rows := the_count.count; 
            RETURN NEXT r; 
        END LOOP; 
        RETURN; 
END;
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

use `select count_em_all();` to call it.

Hope you find this usefull.
Paul

Comment: ERROR:  "r.table_schema" is not a known variable

Answer (score 4):

Here is a much simpler way.

```
tables="$(echo '\dt' | psql -U "${PGUSER}" | tail -n +4 | head -n-2 | tr -d ' ' | cut -d '|' -f2)"
for table in $tables; do
printf "%s: %s\n" "$table" "$(echo "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table;" | psql -U "${PGUSER}" | tail -n +3 | head -n-2 | tr -d ' ')"
done
```

output should look like this

```
auth_group: 0
auth_group_permissions: 0
auth_permission: 36
auth_user: 2
auth_user_groups: 0
auth_user_user_permissions: 0
authtoken_token: 2
django_admin_log: 0
django_content_type: 9
django_migrations: 22
django_session: 0
mydata_table1: 9011
mydata_table2: 3499
```

you can update the `psql -U "${PGUSER}"` portion as needed to access your database

note that the `head -n-2` syntax may not work in macOS, you could probably just use [a different implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481643/how-can-we-remove-last-7-lines-of-file-in-unix) there

Tested on psql (PostgreSQL) 11.2 under CentOS 7

---

if you want it sorted by table, then just wrap it with `sort`

```
for table in $tables; do
printf "%s: %s\n" "$table" "$(echo "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table;" | psql -U "${PGUSER}" | tail -n +3 | head -n-2 | tr -d ' ')"
done | sort -k 2,2nr
```

output;

```
mydata_table1: 9011
mydata_table2: 3499
auth_permission: 36
django_migrations: 22
django_content_type: 9
authtoken_token: 2
auth_user: 2
auth_group: 0
auth_group_permissions: 0
auth_user_groups: 0
auth_user_user_permissions: 0
django_admin_log: 0
django_session: 0
```

Comment: Could you do an actual runnable script as an example - I tried this and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: did you run this in bash? What I posted should be a working bash script (thats how I ran it). Just make sure that you have the bash variable `PGUSER` set (`export PGUSER=myusername`), and that your Postgres is configured to allow you to run commands from `psql -U "${PGUSER}"`, which might require some user account configuration

Comment: Here's what I tried to run: `#!/bin/bash
tables="$(echo '\dt' | psql -U "${PGUSER}" | tail -n +4 | head -n-2 | tr -d ' ' | cut -d '|' -f2)"
for table in $tables; do
printf "%s: %s\n" "$table" "$(echo "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table;" | psql -U "${PGUSER}" -d "${PGDB}" | tail -n +3 | head -n-2 | tr -d '
 ')"
done`  - failed with `psql: error: could not connect to server:` - server **is** running, PGDB is test, PGUSER is pol which always worked before!

Comment: you might want to add `set -ux` at the start of your script so you can see the interpolated commands that are being run, and look closely at the `psql` commands and their args to verify that the correct variables are being populated in those commands. My first guess is that `PGDB` or `PGUSER` are not being passed correctly in your script. The `set -u` should cause the script to halt and give an error message if you are trying to use an unset shell variable. From there, I would try running each `psql` command manually to make sure they really are working individually

Comment: if the `psql` commands really are being interpolated correctly and you still `cannot connect to server` then you might need to investigate your shell environment and compare the environment in your console to that inside the shell script during execution, to make sure that the server is available inside your script when it runs.

Comment: I ran this [bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5724737/470530) from this thread no problem - just changed the -U and -d values! There's nothing wrong with my environment.

Comment: If I put `set -ux` into the script, the output is as follows: `[pol@fedora inst]$ ./cnt.sh 
++ tail -n +4
++ cut -d '|' -f2
./cnt.sh: line 3: PGUSER: unbound variable
++ head -n-2
++ echo '\dt'
++ tr -d ' '
+ tables=
[pol@fedora inst]$`

Comment: Right, it means that you need to make sure the `PGUSER` variable is set in your environment when the script executes. You can set this inside the script with `PGUSER=myusername` or you should be able to set it outside the script with something like `export PGUSER=myusername`. Maybe better to set it inside the script if possible

Comment: in the command that you linked to, the Postgres username is hard-coded. In the one I posted, its set from a shell environment variable. Thats the relevant difference.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a query that outputs the size of each table as well as its number of rows:

```sql
SELECT 
  pg_class.relname AS table_name,
  pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(pg_class.oid)) AS size,
  pg_total_relation_size(pg_class.oid) / (current_setting('block_size')::integer / 1024) AS num_blocks,
  pg_stat_user_tables.n_live_tup AS num_rows
FROM 
  pg_stat_user_tables 
JOIN 
  pg_class ON pg_stat_user_tables.relid = pg_class.oid 
WHERE 
  pg_class.relnamespace = (SELECT oid FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspname='public')
ORDER BY 
  pg_total_relation_size(pg_class.oid) DESC;
```

Comment: I get numrows = 0 - check [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/T8tAlq2l).

Answer (score 1):

I like Daniel Vérité's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28709658/1138946).
But when you can't use a CREATE statement you can either use a [bash solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5724737/1138946) or, if you're a windows user, a powershell one:

```
# You don't need this if you have pgpass.conf
$env:PGPASSWORD = "userpass"

# Get table list
$tables = & 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\psql.exe' -U user -w -d dbname -At -c "select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_type='BASE TABLE' AND table_schema='schema1'"

foreach ($table in $tables) {
    & 'C:\path_to_postresql\bin\psql.exe' -U root -w -d dbname -At -c "select '$table', count(*) from $table"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted the total from all tables + a list of tables with their counts. A little like a performance chart of where most time was spent

```
WITH results AS ( 
  SELECT nspname AS schemaname,relname,reltuples
    FROM pg_class C
    LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
    WHERE 
      nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') AND
      relkind='r'
     GROUP BY schemaname, relname, reltuples
)

SELECT * FROM results
UNION
SELECT 'all' AS schemaname, 'all' AS relname, SUM(reltuples) AS "reltuples" FROM results

ORDER BY reltuples DESC
```

You could of course put a `LIMIT` clause on the results in this version too so that you get the largest `n` offenders as well as a total.

One thing that should be noted about this is that you need to let it sit for a while after bulk imports. I tested this by just adding 5000 rows to a database across several tables using real import data. It showed 1800 records for about a minute (probably a configurable window)

This is based from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2611745/1548557 work, so thank you and recognition to that for the query to use within the CTE

Answer (score 1):

If you're in the `psql` shell, using [`\gexec`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#:%7E:text=%5Cgexec) allows you to execute the syntax described in [syed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62870937/4709762) and [Aur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38683586/4709762) without manual edits in an external text editor.

```sql
with x (y) as (
    select
        'select count(*), '''||
        tablename||
        ''' as "tablename" from '||
        tablename||' '
    from pg_tables
    where schemaname='public'
)
select
    string_agg(y,' union all '||chr(10)) || ' order by tablename'
from x \gexec
```

Note, [`string_agg()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43944/4709762) is used both to delimit `union all` between statements and to smush the separated datarows into a single unit to be passed into the buffer.

> `\gexec`
>
> Sends the current query buffer to the server, then treats each column of each  row of the query's output (if any) as a SQL statement to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

below query will give us row count and size for each table

select table_schema, table_name,
pg_relation_size('"'||table_schema||'"."'||table_name||'"')/1024/1024 size_MB,
(xpath('/row/c/text()', query_to_xml(format('select count(*) AS c from %I.%I', table_schema, table_name),
false, true,'')))[1]::text::int AS rows_n
from information_schema.tables
order by size_MB desc;

Comment: The formatting can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest and extreamly fast methods to get a good enough estimate on the amount of rows for each table:

```sql
SELECT relname, reltuples AS estimate 
FROM pg_class 
WHERE relname IN (
  SELECT TABLE_NAME
  FROM information_schema.tables
  WHERE TABLE_NAME not like 'pg_%' AND table_schema in ('public')
) 
ORDER BY estimate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I normally which can return estimated row count and actual row count (You should change your database name to match your requirement). You can use pg_class or some pg_% tables to double check and choose your best estimated
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/monitoring-stats.html

```sql
-- Count rows of all tables inside a PostgreSQL database
WITH tbl AS (SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables 
             WHERE table_catalog = 'adventureworks' AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'  AND 
             table_name NOT LIKE 'pg_%' AND table_schema NOT LIKE 'information_schema')
SELECT tbl.table_catalog AS "Database",
    tbl.table_schema AS "SCHEMA",
    tbl.table_name AS "TABLE_NAME",
    (tbl.table_schema || '.' || tbl.table_name) AS "caller",
    pg_total_relation_size(tbl.table_schema || '.' || tbl.table_name) / 1024 AS size_kb , 
    (pg_total_relation_size(tbl.table_schema || '.' || tbl.table_name))::real / 1024 / 1024 AS size_mb ,
    s.n_live_tup AS estimated_row_count,
    (xpath('/row/c/text()', query_to_xml(format('select count(*) as c from %I.%I', tbl.table_schema, tbl.table_name), FALSE, TRUE, '')))[1]::text::bigint AS "true_row_count"
FROM tbl INNER JOIN pg_stat_user_tables s ON tbl.table_name = s.relname
ORDER BY caller;
```