# How can I find tablename and row count of all the tables?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I want to find tablename and row count  of all the tables in a database in mysql and pgsql by using query. Is there any query to find this?

Comment: no idea for postgres. for mysql, look in the information_schema db, which has the per db/table/field metadata

Comment: Refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html for MySql

Answer (score 1):

The [SQL-standard `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` provides information about the structure of your database](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html) - which tables it has, etc. It does not, however, contain row counts.

At least for PostgreSQL you have at least two options for getting row counts:

- Use an external program or a PL/PgSQL function that generates dynamic SQL using `EXECUTE` to do a `SELECT count(*) FROM tablename` for each table found in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` (excluding system tables); or
- Run `ANALYZE` then get the *approximate* rowcounts from the PostgreSQL statistics tables. This approach is a lot faster, but is only getting an approximate table rowcount based on statistical sampling and estimation.

This has been discussed in detail for PostgreSQL [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2596670/398670).

The approach of querying `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` for a table list and then looping over the tables doing `count` should be portable across all databases. Other approaches will likely require various degrees of database-specific code.

Answer (score 0):

For postgresql:

```
SELECT 
nspname AS schema,relname table_name,reltuples::int rows_count

FROM pg_class C
LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)

WHERE 

  nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') AND
  relkind='r'  and reltuples>0
ORDER BY relname  ;
```