# Rails, Active Record - number of rows in tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, heroku

I got an email from Heroku saying I have too many rows in my Postgres DB.

How can I see how many rows I have in each table (so I can prioritize deletion)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`heroku pg:psql (specify database name here if you have more than one)`

Then check out this post to get a row count in postgres

[How do you find the row count for all your tables in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596670/how-do-you-find-the-row-count-for-all-your-tables-in-postgres)

Answer (score 2):

A better way to look at this might be:

## How many records do I have for each of my AR models?

While it may not exactly match the numbers Heroku gives (may be a bit lower), and may have some extra stuff (that are not models), but for practical purposes, this is best option and it avoids the need to use SQL.

`ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.map { |d| [d.all.size, d.name] }.sort`

#### Explanation:

`ActiveRecord::Base.descendants` is a quick way to get all of the AR models. This is used to create an array of arrays that contains the `[number of records, model name]` to allow for simple lexicographic sorting. This should be enough to quickly determine where all your rows are going.