# how can we remove last 7 lines of file in unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

How to remove last 7 lines from the csv file using unix commands.

For example -

abc
bffkms
slds
Row started 1
Row started 2
Row started 3
Row started 4
Row started 5
Row started 6
Row started 7

I want to delete the last 7 lines from above file. Please suggest.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `head`

```
head -n-7 file
```

from man page:

```
 -n, --lines=[-]K
              print the first K lines instead of the first 10;
              with the leading '-', print all but the last K lines of each file
```

like:

```
kent$ seq 10|head -n-7
1
2
3
```

Comment: Note, this does not work on Mac OSX, as a negative value is not a valid parameter for the `-n` flag.

Answer (score 1):

An `tac` `awk` combination.

```
tac | awk  'NR>7' | tac
```

eks:

```
seq 1 10 | tac | awk  'NR>7' | tac
1
2
3
```

---

Another `awk` version

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a++;next} FNR<a-7 ' file{,}
```

This reads the file twice `{,}`, first counts line, second prints all but last `7` lines.