# Do a Postgres for loop that SELECTs data from each table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I want to loop through each table in my database, and print it's row count.

I can get all table names, but I do not know how to loop through them, assigning `SELECT COUNT(*)` to its table.

```
-- Get all tablenames
SELECT relname
FROM pg_stat_user_tables
```

**Example Result**

```
table_name     row_count
-------------  -------------
users          321
questions      807
comments       3,145
tags           58
...
```

**Note:**
I know you can use `pg_stat_user_tables` to get every table's row counts, but I want to see a "hello world" Postgres loop that SELECTS values. I couldn't find any other SO question or example online that was this simplified.

Comment: See [How do you find the row count for all your tables in Postgres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596670)

Comment: Are you referring to @Paul's answer? It doesn't work if you try to run it. Gives a syntax error

Comment: Not this one specifically, but reading all these answers closely, I'm surprised that none of them is good for exact counts. I've just submitted [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28709658/238814).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you'll need to create a Pl/SQL procedure for that as [documented](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) in PostgreSQL manual.

Inside your [loop](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html) write something like:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT count(*) FROM ' || tabname::regclass;
```