# Perform the sum of many count queries, from the result of an initial query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to write a query that counts every object in the database. I'm aware that you can query for statistics, but I want to know how to write this general type of query in case I need to do it again.

I have the results of this query, which gives every table name in the DB:

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='public'
AND table_type='BASE TABLE'
```

The results look something like this:

```
table_name
----------
queue_classic_jobs
activities
attachments
comments
csv_files
```

I want to do a `count(*)` on each table for each resulting row:

```
table_name        |      row_count
----------------------------------
queue_classic_jobs               6
activities                       2
attachments                      4
comments                         8
csv_files                       10
```

and then sum the row_count column. What should my query look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use plpgsql `EXECUTE` command.

You have two options. The first is anonymous code block with temporary table to save results:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS results(table_name text, row_count bigint);
TRUNCATE results;
DO $$
DECLARE
    tname text;
BEGIN
    FOR tname IN
        SELECT table_name
        FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_schema='public'
        AND table_type='BASE TABLE'
    LOOP
        EXECUTE format($fmt$
            INSERT INTO results
            SELECT '%s', count(*) from %s
            $fmt$, tname, tname);
    END LOOP;
END $$;

SELECT * FROM results
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TOTAL', sum(row_count) FROM results;
```

The second option is a plpgsql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION show_row_count()
RETURNS TABLE (table_name text, row_count bigint)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
    tname text;
BEGIN
    FOR tname IN
        SELECT i.table_name
        FROM information_schema.tables i
        WHERE table_schema='public'
        AND table_type='BASE TABLE'
    LOOP
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format($fmt$
            SELECT '%s'::text, count(*) from %s
            $fmt$, tname, tname);
    END LOOP;
END $$;

WITH row_counts AS (SELECT * FROM show_row_count())
SELECT * FROM row_counts
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TOTAL'::text, sum(row_count) FROM row_counts;
```

Read more: [Executing Dynamic Commands](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

Answer (score 1):

If you want tables with individual row_counts do

```
SELECT nspname AS schemaname,relname,reltuples
FROM pg_class C
LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
WHERE 
  nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') AND
  relkind='r' 
ORDER BY reltuples DESC
```

`

For total count of all rows in all tables do

```
With infotables as
(
SELECT nspname AS schemaname,relname,reltuples
FROM pg_class C
LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
WHERE 
  nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') AND
  relkind='r' 
ORDER BY reltuples DESC
)
select sum(reltuples) from infotables`
```

Reference:[How do you find the row count for all your tables in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596670/how-do-you-find-the-row-count-for-all-your-tables-in-postgres)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I'm not really interested in the actual row count. I'd like to learn how to write the more general version of the query. I had already found the link you've provided

Answer (score 1):

You can use analytic functions to get the total count in each row.

```
            SELECT
                nspname AS schemaname,
                relname AS TABLE_NAME,
                reltuples AS ROW_COUNT,
                SUM (reltuples) OVER () AS total_rows_count
            FROM
                pg_class C
            LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C .relnamespace)
            WHERE
                nspname = 'ptab'
            AND relkind = 'r'
            ORDER BY
                reltuples DESC
```