# How to execute a dynamic SQL statement in a single Select statement?

Tags: regex, postgresql, dynamic-sql

I just wonder how to eval the content of dynamic SQL using one select; this is the example. This is only an example. but I would like dynamically functions, and manage using single selects. ( I know that sqls are only for SELECT instead of modify... but In this deep querentee Im becomeing in a crazy developer)

```
SELECT 'SELECT SETVAL(' || chr(39) || c.relname || chr(39)|| ' , 
(SELECT MAX(Id)+1 FROM '  || regexp_replace(c.relname, '_[a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?', '', 'g')   ||' ), true );' 
FROM pg_class c WHERE c.relkind = 'S';
```

### The original output is:

```
SELECT SETVAL('viewitem_id_seq' , (SELECT MAX(Id)+1 FROM viewitem ), true );
SELECT SETVAL('userform_id_seq' , (SELECT MAX(Id)+1 FROM userform ), true );
```

This is the dynamic sentence:
(SELECT MAX(Id)+1 FROM '  || regexp_replace(c.relname, '*[a-zA-Z]+*[a-zA-Z]+(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?', '', 'g')

is an string that generates as output a SQL, how to eval in the same line this statement?

### The desired output is:

```
SELECT SETVAL('viewitem_id_seq' , 25, true );
SELECT SETVAL('userform_id_seq' , 85, true );
```

thanks!

Comment: Why does it need to be a single query?

Comment: because I need create an dynamic-statement that affect the original statement to perform nested join, or sub-selects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those are `serial` or `identity` columns it would be better to use `pg_get_serial_sequence()` to get the link between a table's column and its sequence.

You can actually run dynamic SQL inside a SQL statement by using `query_to_xml()`

I use the following script if I need to synchronize the sequences for `serial` (or `identity`) columns with their actual values:

```
with sequences as (
  -- this query is only to identify all sequences that belong to a column
  -- it's essentially similar to your select * from pg_class where reltype = 'S'
  -- but returns the sequence name, table and column name to which the 
  -- sequence belongs
  select *
  from (
    select table_schema,
           table_name,
           column_name,
           pg_get_serial_sequence(format('%I.%I', table_schema, table_name), column_name) as col_sequence
    from information_schema.columns
    where table_schema not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
  ) t
  where col_sequence is not null
), maxvals as (
  select table_schema, table_name, column_name, col_sequence,
         --
         -- this is the "magic" that runs the SELECT MAX() query
         --
          (xpath('/row/max/text()',
             query_to_xml(format('select max(%I) from %I.%I', column_name, table_schema, table_name), true, true, ''))
          )[1]::text::bigint as max_val
  from sequences
) 
select table_schema, 
       table_name, 
       column_name, 
       col_sequence,
       coalesce(max_val, 0) as max_val,
       setval(col_sequence, coalesce(max_val, 1)) --<< this uses the value from the dynamic query
from maxvals;
```

The dynamic part here is the call to `query_to_xml()`

First I use `format()`  to properly deal with identifiers. It also makes writing the SQL easier as no concatenation is required. So for every table returned by the first CTE, something like this is executed:

```
query_to_xml('select max(id) from public.some_table', true, true, '')
```

This returns something like:

```xml
<row xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <max>42</max>
</row>
```

The value is than extracted from the XML value using xpath() and converted to a number which then is used in the final SELECT to actually call `setval()`

The nesting with multiple CTEs is only used to make each part more readable.

The same approach can e.g. used to [find the row count for all tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596670)

Some [background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49281340) on how `query_to_xml()` works

Comment: The idea is excellent, but the concept is how to invoke a dynamic sql result set as part of the stament of the original statement.

Comment: @FabioPalm: that's the `query_to_xml()` as I have explained. If you need to extract more than a single value from that, you will need to use e.g. `xmltable()`

Comment: Its possible to perform an inner from xmltable function?