# Count rows in all schemas (with permission granted) in all tables

Tags: postgresql, count, schema, database-table

I'm trying to count the rows in all the tables in the database. Since the answer I'd like to get must differentiate between different schemas I also take into account the schema that a particular table is located in.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28709658/8201676) has been most helpful but it turns out I don't have access privilege to all schemas in the database.

I know that I can check my privileges for a particular table or schema by executing the following query:

```
select count(*) from (
SELECT grantee, privilege_type 
FROM information_schema.role_table_grants 
WHERE table_name='data' and privilege_type = 'SELECT') as foo
```

and checking if the output is equal to or greater than one.

My code at the moment is as follows:

```
CREATE or replace function rowcount_all(schema_name text default 'public')
  RETURNS table(table_name_var text, cnt bigint) as
$$
declare
 table_name_var text;
begin
  for table_name_var in SELECT c.relname FROM pg_class c
    JOIN pg_namespace s ON (c.relnamespace=s.oid)
    WHERE c.relkind = 'r' AND s.nspname=schema_name
  loop
    if (
    select count(*) from (
    SELECT grantee, privilege_type 
    FROM information_schema.role_table_grants 
    WHERE table_name=table_name_var and privilege_type = 'SELECT') as foo
  ) >= 1 then 
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('select cast(%L as text),count(*) from %I.%I',
       table_name_var, schema_name, table_name_var);
    end if;
  END loop;
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

While executing the following query

```
WITH rc(schema_name,tbl) AS (
  select s.n,rowcount_all(s.n) from (values ('schema1'),
    ('schema2'), ('schema3'), ('schema4')) as s(n)
)
SELECT schema_name,(tbl).* FROM rc;
```

I get an error that `ERROR: permission denied for relation table1` where `table1` is in the schema that I don't have access to. I presume that my logic in the IF statement somehow doesn't filter out the tables I don't have access to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`information_schema`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema), being an SQL-standard representation of the database metadata, is useful if you're trying to build something portable, but often a little unwieldy if you're just trying to administer a Postgres server.

The easiest way to check privileges is to use the [privilege check functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-ACCESS-TABLE). I believe this will return only the tables you are able to query:

```
select oid::regclass::text
from pg_class
where relkind = 'r'
  and relnamespace = schema_name::regnamespace
  and has_schema_privilege(relnamespace, 'USAGE')
  and has_any_column_privilege(oid, 'SELECT')
```

Note that yours is one of the rare cases where `has_any_column_privilege()` is useful (compared with the more obvious `has_table_privilege()`), since you don't need full table privileges for a `select count(*)`, just access to one of the columns (but it doesn't matter which).

Note also that the `oid::regclass::text` will return a table name which is already quoted and schema-qualified (if necessary), so your `format()` call can use a simple `%s` instead of `%I.%I`.

If you can make do with an approximate and slightly out-of-date record count, you can bypass the privilege checks entirely (and save yourself a whole lot of table scans) by querying the stats from the last `VACUUM` run:

```
select
  oid::regclass::text,
  reltuples
from pg_class
where relkind = 'r'
  and relnamespace = schema_name::regnamespace
```

Comment: @balkon16: Updated my answer to cover an edge case I overlooked, plus an alternative approach which you might find useful