# Dynamic count for each table by stored procedure in database in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a database with 18 tables. I want to create a stored procedure to individually get all tables count with the help of loop based condition. I have done manually, but I want to do dynamically (please don't mark duplicate). I searched a lot about this question, but I could not find the solution. Finally I came to the stack overflow.

Example output:

```
 table_1   2108
 table_2   4320
 table_3   4257
 table_4   2198  
 table_5    310
```

Comment: What's wrong with the many solutions given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596670/how-do-you-find-the-row-count-for-all-your-tables-in-postgres? [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28709658/330315) looks like the solution you are after

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name; i am unable to understand that. because i am new to postgresql. so can you give  sample solution .