# Get count of all materialized views

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get a count from all materialized views in my database. This is what I have so far, but it is not returning the count -

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
    rec record;
    my_pk_new integer;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN 
        SELECT matviewname
        FROM pg_matviews  
        limit 2
    LOOP
    EXECUTE ' SELECT count(*) from' || rec.matviewname
    INTO my_pk_new;
    END LOOP;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Calling (%)', my_pk_new;

END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This is what I would expect to see -

```
Matview A    2432
Matview B    453984
```

Comment: You can use the same strategy as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38684225/330315

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) After `from` a space is missing. So you are executing the query

```
SELECT count(*) frommy_view
```

instead of

```
SELECT count(*) from my_view
```

So there is an error. On my system a default int value returned (`1`)

2) Your `RAISE NOTICE` is outside the loop. So you are noticing only the very last query result. Put this into the loop body and it works.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    rec record;
    my_pk_new integer;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN 
        SELECT matviewname
        FROM pg_matviews  
        limit 2
    LOOP
        EXECUTE 'SELECT count(*) FROM ' || rec.matviewname
        INTO my_pk_new;

        RAISE NOTICE 'Calling (%)', my_pk_new;   
    END LOOP;       
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am still getting just the last value.

Comment: Are you sure, that you moved the RAISE NOTICE into the LOOP?

Comment: Because I don't know any fiddle engine which supports "Raise Notice", I converted your anonymous function into a normal function. But it does the same: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=44213c55f9d554718a2c2833a81c0d7b

Comment: How do I select the result into a table? I would much rather do that instead of raising a notice.

Comment: see the fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=44213c55f9d554718a2c2833a81c0d7b

Comment: How do I get the matviewname returned as well? Right now it is only giving me the counts and I don't know for what mat view they are.

Comment: changed the fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=62b77565ceab1e8c01c3d65cc3823098

Comment: Your new fiddle is giving me this error - `set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set.
`

Comment: The fiddle itself? Or your code? The fiddle works for me without any problem. Please try to reproduce it with a fiddle as well