# How to check content loading status on a static database?

Tags: postgresql, count, row, verification, database-table

We have a static database we constantly update with loader scripts. These loader scripts get current information from third party sources, clean it and upload it to database.

I have already made some SQL scripts to ensure schemas and tables required exists. Now I'd like to check that each table has the expected row count.

I did something like this:

```
select case when count(*) = <someNumber>
  then 'someSchema.someTable OK'
  else 'someSchema.someTable BAD row count' end
from someSchema.someTable;
```

But doing these kind of queries for ~300 tables is cumbersome.

Now I was thinking maybe there's a way to have a table like:

```
create table expected_row_count (
  schema_name varchar,
  table_name varchar,
  row_count bigint
);
```

And somehow test all listed tables and **only output** the ones that fail the count check. But I'm kind of missing now... Should I try to write a function? Can a table like this be used to build queries and execute them?

Comment: You can join your `expected_row_count` table against something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38684225

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whole credit goes to [@a-horse_with*_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) , I'm posting a reply for completeness:

## Check row count

First let's create some data to test the query:

```
create schema if not exists data;

create table if not exists data.test1 (nothing int);
create table if not exists data.test2 (nothing int);

insert into data.test1 (nothing)
  (select random() from generate_series(1, 28));

insert into data.test2 (nothing)
  (select random() from generate_series(1, 55));

create table if not exists public.expected_row_count (
  table_schema varchar not null default '',
  table_name varchar not null default '',
  row_count bigint not null default 0
);

insert into public.expected_row_count (table_schema, table_name, row_count) values
  ('data', 'test1', (select count(*) from data.test1)),
  ('data', 'test2', (select count(*) from data.test2))
  ;
```

Now the query to check the data:

```
select * from (
  select
    table_schema,
    table_name,
    (xpath('/row/cnt/text()', xml_count))[1]::text::int as row_count
  from (
    select
      table_schema,
      table_name,
      query_to_xml(format('select count(*) as cnt from %I.%I', table_schema, table_name), false, true, '') as xml_count
    from information_schema.tables
    where table_schema = 'data' --<< change here for the schema you want
  ) infs ) as r

inner join expected_row_count erc
  on r.table_schema = erc.table_schema
  and r.table_name = erc.table_name
  and r.row_count != erc.row_count
 ;
```

Previous query should give an empty results if all counts are ok, and the
tables with missing data if not. To check it, update the count for some
table on `expected_row_count` and re-run the query. For example:

```
update expected_row_count set row_count = 666 where table_name = 'test1';
```