# Rails 5 Console Query to Count ALL Records in the DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Is there a command/query I can run in the rails console to count all records of all models that are in the DB?

(Using Rails 5 and Postgres)

Answer (score 1):

All active record models are descendants of ApplicationRecord, so you can do...

```
ApplicationRecord.descendants.map(&:count).inject(:+)
```

Note that outside production, classes tend to be loaded only when required, so if you're interested in getting the count fort a non-production environment (e.g. development) you would need to modify the configuation to ensure all records are loaded.  In `config/environment/development.rb` set

```
config.eager_load = true
```

You can leave it as such but it will slow down your development server startup time. Personally I don't find it a problem but it depends on the size of your application.

Note that... as pointed out by max in the comments,  if you do `reload!` in your console, your `ApplicationRecord.descendants` will be an empty array.

Comment: There is a really big problem with this in development as `ApplicationRecord.descendants` is lazy loading and will only show classes that have been referenced.

Comment: @max good point. If op is concerned about production then of course not an issue. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: There are still issues with just setting `config.eager_load = true` as `ApplicationRecord.descendants` relies on the class cache. For example if you run `reload!`. `ApplicationRecord.descendants` is suddenly empty again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table|
  next if table.classify.safe_constantize.nil?
  count = table.classify.safe_constantize.count
  puts "#{table} -> #{count}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a one-liner but this handles non-conventional models where the table name does not match the class name. It uses ApplicationRecord.descents but handles the caveat that its lazy loading:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  # ApplicationRecord.descendants is lazy loading so we must
  # force rails to load all the models
  def self.eager_load_descendants!
    Dir.glob(Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '**', '*.rb')).map do |pn|
      require_dependency pn
    end
  end

  def self.count_all_models
    eager_load_descendants!
    descendants.each_with_object({}) do |model, hash|
      hash[model.model_name.plural] = model.count
    end
  end
end
```

It returns a hash:

```
{"users"=>5, "rainbows"=>2, "ponies"=>0}
```

If you want a total sum you can just do:

```
irb(main):002:0> {"users"=>5, "rainbows"=>2, "ponies"=>0}.values.sum
=> 7
```

Comment: Also if you just want a row count of all the tables you can query [pg_stat_user_tables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2611745/544825).