# export/query the latest record of the tables of database in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, greenplum

I want to query a database which will select the schema_name,max(date_column),table_name from database in PostgreSQL.

is there any process from which we can achieve the above scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres you can use a variation of the "[row count for all tables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38684225)" approach:

```
select table_schema, table_name,
       (xpath( '/row/max/text()', 
               query_to_xml(format('select max(%I) from %I.%I', column_name, table_schema, table_name), true, true, '')
              )
       )[1]::text::int as max_value
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'public' --<< adjust for your schema name(s)
  and column_name = 'date_column' --<< adjust for the real name of your column
```

Comment: Hi,I tried with the above query, I just replace the table_schema and column_name  in where condition , I am getting below error:                                                          "ERROR:  function format(unknown, information_schema.sql_identifier, information_schema.sql_identifier, information_schema.sql_identifier) does not exist
LINE 3:                query_to_xml(format('select max(%I) from %I.%...
                                    ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts."

Comment: This works in Postgres. Which database product are you really using?

Comment: Yeah I am using postgre (greenplum) only

Comment: Greeplum or Postgres? Those are two very different database products. Does Greenplum support `format()` and `query_to_xml()`? Does it work if cast the paramters? `format('....', column_date::text, table_name::text, table_schema::text)`