# list table sizes for all tables in a postgresql database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I can get the number of columns in all the tables in a postgresql database by

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COUNT(*) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
GROUP BY TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME;
```

I can get the number of rows in a **specific** table in a database by

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM mytable
```

How to obtain column **and** row counts for all table in a database in one query?

Comment: Given that Oracle doesn't support `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, your question is suspicious.  Please tag with the database youa re really using.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596670/how-do-you-find-the-row-count-for-all-your-tables-in-postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I can not find an answer at that page i.e. how to get row and column counts at once

Comment: All of those answer will give you the row count for each table. They can easily  be extended to include the column count (especially [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38684225))

Comment: the "easy extension" is in fact my original question thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine your query using a [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) and join it with the one [`posted on this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2611745/2275388), as @a_horse_with_no_name suggested, e.g.

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT table_schema, table_name, count(*) AS count_columns
  FROM information_schema.columns
  GROUP BY table_schema, table_name
) 
SELECT 
  nspname AS schemaname,relname,reltuples,count_columns
FROM pg_class C
LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
JOIN j ON j.table_name = relname AND j.table_schema = nspname 
WHERE 
  nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') AND
  relkind='r' 
ORDER BY reltuples DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either enter \d+ in the selected database using psql from the command line or use the SQL statements from here:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage