# Postgres SQL query across different schemas

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have multiple schemas, I would like to run a simple count query across schemas such as:

```
SELECT COUNT(col_x) FROM schema1.table WHENRE col_x IS NOT NULL
```

I saw that I'm able to get all the schemas with:

```
SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata
```

So by using:

```
set search_path to schema1; 
SELECT COUNT(col_x)
FROM table
WHERE col_x is not NULL;
```

I was able to run the query for schema1

The question is - is it possible to run in a loop and use the schema name as a parameter for search_path and run the query across all schemas? or any other efficient way to do so?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596670/how-do-you-find-the-row-count-for-all-your-tables-in-postgres

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need some `plpgsql` and dynamic SQL for this. Here is an anonymous block for illustration:

```sql
do language plpgsql
$$
declare
 v_schema_name text;
 table_row_count bigint;
 sysSchema text[] := array['pg_toast','pg_temp_1','pg_toast_temp_1','pg_catalog','public','information_schema'];
 -- other declarations here
begin
 for v_schema_name in SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE (schema_name != ALL(sysSchema)) loop
   begin
     execute format('select count(col_x) from %I.t_table', v_schema_name)
     into table_row_count;
     raise notice 'Schema % count %', v_schema_name, table_row_count;
   exception when others then null;  -- t_table may not exists in some schemata
   end;
 -- other statements here
 end loop;
end;
$$;
```

And btw `WHERE col_x is not NULL` is redundant.

Comment: Seems like the query workd, but raise notice 'Schema % count %', schema_name, table_row_count; was not printing anything wastrying to run change it to raise instead by same thing how can i validate the output?

Comment: Pls. comment the `exception` line in order to see what's wrong. I edited my answer, format fits better than replace.

Comment: Right -
ERROR:  column reference "schema_name" is ambiguous
LINE 1: SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata

Comment: My mistake. The "schema_name" variable and field had the same name. Edited my answer, changed the variable to "v_schema_name", should be OK now.

Comment: I see a major problem. The exception handler. As written this is a a pure bug. If a an error occurs your routine terminates prematurely. Meaning you get the wrong answer and have **no way to find out why**. At a minimum log/print the error. Even better if you are not prepared to write corrective code then do not capture the exception.

Comment: @Belayer you are right. This is an illustration only, but as you noticed a very wrong one. Yet another edit. The `exception` statement may be developed in order to handle the case correctly.

Comment: Adding filtering to the sys schemas - working as charm now :) thanks! BTW - edit your answer