# PostgreSQL: How to query all tables with exact number of lines

Tags: postgresql

There are [lots of similar posts like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596670/) to query the number of lines for all tables in a PostggreSQL database, but these provides the estimated values; I need the exact one which I can find with

```
SELECT count(*) FROM "TableName";
```

How to combine this into a query to list all tables

```
SELECT tables.table_name AS "TabName"
   FROM information_schema.tables
  ORDER BY tables.table_name;
```

Additional: Each table has an ID-number as first column but for each table these column-names are different. Is there a way to find the name for the first column for all tables and to find the maximum value; ideally combined into the above query which should provide then three columns:

1. TableName
2. NumberOfLines
3. maxID

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38684225/

Comment: Great, thank you! Works fine. Do you have an idea to find the max-value in the first (ID) columns?