# Iterate through schemas

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have several schemas in my database. Most of the schemas have a table called `orders`. How do I iterate through the schemas that have that table and get a count of the number of records in each of those schemas for that table?

Comment: See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38684225)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select * from information_schema.schemata;`

see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/infoschema-schemata.html

---

```
do
$$
declare
    tableName varchar := 'xyz';
    schemaName varchar;
    query text;
    counter integer;
begin
    for schemaName in select table_schema from information_schema.tables where table_name = tableName
        loop
            query := 'select count(*) from ' || schemaName || '.' || tableName;
            execute query into counter;
            raise notice E'%  %', schemaName, counter;
        end loop ;

end $$
```