# Looping through all tables and columns in postgresql and applying a select query to each one

Tags: postgresql

I came up with this idea to loop over all tables and column names to count the number of null values in postgres. However, I failed to do that by Error 42702: column reference "table_name" is ambiguous.

```
create or replace function count_nulls()
    returns table ("table_name" text, "column_name" text, "nulls" int)
    language plpgsql as
$func$
    declare _record information_schema.columns %ROWTYPE;
    begin
        for _record in
            SELECT "table_name", "column_name"
            FROM information_schema.columns
            where "table_schema" = 'public'
        loop
            select quote_literal(_record.table_name) as "table",
                 quote_literal(_record.column_name) as "column", 
                 count(*) as "nulls"
            from quote_literal(_record.table_name)
            where quote_literal(_record.column_name) is null
            group by "table", "column";
        end loop;
        return;
    end;
$func$;

select * from count_nulls();
```

Any pointers to documentation or keywords for further search is appreciated.

Comment: You need [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) for this. Alternatively, you can adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2611745)

Answer (score 1):

Change this block :

```
for _record in
    SELECT "table_name", "column_name"
    FROM information_schema.columns
    where "table_schema" = 'public'
loop
```

to this:

```
for _record in
    SELECT t1."table_name", t1."column_name"
    FROM information_schema.columns t1
    where t1."table_schema" = 'public'
loop
```

Comment: And you have incorrect syntax on your function.  Firstly, your function must be return table but inside the function you have not return query clause.