# PostgreSQL How to use the value of one SELECT as the table name of another SELECT

Tags: postgresql

First，I need to query the sequence name

```
SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence('user', 'user_id')； -- public.user_id_seq
```

Then，I need to query the last value

```
SELECT last_value FROM public.user_id_seq ;
```

How to combine these two queries？

I tried three ways, but none was right

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence('user', 'user_id')
  )
SELECT * FROM t;
```

```
WITH tableName AS ( VALUES ( pg_get_serial_sequence('user', 'user_id') ) ) 
SELECT * FROM tableName
```

```
do
$$
declare 
    _query text ;
    _cursor CONSTANT refcursor :='_cursor';
begin
    _query:=format('SELECT * FROM %s ', (SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence('user', 'user_id')));
    open _cursor for execute _query;
end;
$$;
fetch all from _cursor;  -- cursor "_cursor" does not exist
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a cursor? that's just overhead

Comment: I saw others use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for PL/pgSQL or dynamic SQL.

You can use `query_to_xml()` to do this purely in SQL (similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38684225/330315))

```
with xml_result as (
  select query_to_xml(format('select last_value from %s', seq_name), true, true, '') as data
  from pg_get_serial_sequence('public.user', 'user_id') as seq_name
)
select (xpath('/row/last_value/text()', data))[1]::text::bigint as last_value
from xml_result;
```