# SQL While loop from select in another select

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, while-loop, subquery

Need some help trying to solve this issue.
I have a query from the database itself to get me the table_schema names and create a row number:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA), TABLE_SCHEMA
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA like 'test\_%'
ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA
```

And I want to create a while loop with this query to give me data from each table with this query:

```
Select 
count('list'),
name 
From test_123.order
group by name
```

So something like this pseudo code:

```
While row_number less than total rows
Select 
count('list'),
name 
From concat((SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA), TABLE_SCHEMA
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA like 'test\_%'
ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA),'.order')
group by name
```

In the end I want to get this:

| ROW_NUMBER | TABLE_SCHEMA | name | count('list') |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test_123 | Jack | 100 |
| 2 | test_234 | Ripper | 200 |

Is this possible to achieve?

Kind regards

Comment: mysql has no loop in sql only in procdures

Comment: after some thought, you should do it in a procedure with a cursor and dynamic sql

Comment: Probably a duplicate - did you try searching..

Comment: Yes I did try to search for it however I couldn't find anything. Can you point me to something please?

Comment: Had to edit, by mistake I've choosen mysql but it's Postgres

Comment: Can't you simply `JOIN` instead?

Comment: Can't you use the information from pg_stat_user_tables? Gives you all tables and for all tables the number of live records. It's about a zillion times faster than counting each table.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596670)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's almost that but with that I can't get the full data I need. I also need the name, not only the count. How can I achieve that?